# Tensorflow How to iterate on or convert the output of tf.train.batch?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to make a Nearest Neighbor algorithm to classify images into 2 classes. I'm working with examples and codes from https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples

The following is a snippet of code results in Xtr and Ytr to be 2 arrays that I can loop on with a statement like `for i in range(len(Xte)):` and index them like `Xte[i, :]`.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data 
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
Xtr, Ytr = mnist.train.next_batch(5000) #5000 for training
Xte, Yte = mnist.test.next_batch(200) #200 for testing
```

This code can be found here https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/nearest_neighbor.ipynb

What I'm trying to do now is do the same with my own dataset of images and I follow the example from: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/5_DataManagement/build_an_image_dataset.ipynb to build my own dataset

The following statement is used after decoding and resizing the images and generates a batch of tensors that represents the images with their labels, however I can't use them and loop on them like what I did above:

```
X, Y = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=batch_size*8, num_threads=4)
```

**My question is how to use those tensors and how to iterate over them or parse them to arrays in order to use them the same way as above?**

Here is the full definition of my function read_images that I use to generate the batch:

```
N_CLASSES = 2
IMG_HEIGHT = 28
IMG_WIDTH = 28
CHANNELS = 1

def read_images(dataset_path, batch_size):
    imagepaths, labels = list(), list()
    label = 0
    try:
        classes = sorted(os.walk(dataset_path).next()[1])
    except:
        classes = sorted(os.walk(dataset_path).__next__()[1])

    for c in classes:
        c_dir = os.path.join(dataset_path, c)
        try:
            walk = os.walk(c_dir).next()
        except:
            walk = os.walk(c_dir).__next__()

        for sample in walk[2]:
            if(sample.endswith('.jpg') or sample.endswith('.jpeg')):
                imagepaths.append(os.path.join(c_dir, sample))
                labels.append(label)
    imagepaths = tf.convert_to_tensor(imagepaths, dtype=tf.string)
    labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.int32)

    image, label = tf.train.slice_input_producer([imagepaths, labels], shuffle=True)

    image = tf.read_file(image)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=CHANNELS)

    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH])

    image = image * 1.0/127.5 - 1.0

    X, Y = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=batch_size*8, num_threads=4)
    return X, Y
```